Captive Portal In MicroPython doesnt work
I am trying to create an automatic captive portal using a Raspberry Pi Pico H with an ESP8266 Wi-Fi HAT. When I connect to the Wi-Fi, it works, but the user is not automatically redirected to the captive portal.
Here my program:
from machine import UART, Pin
import time
import st7789
import vga1_8x8 as f
import vga1_16x16 as f2

uart = UART(0, baudrate=115200, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1))  

def send_command(command, delay=1):
    uart.write(command + '\r\n')
    time.sleep(delay)
    response = uart.read()
    if response:
        print(response.decode('utf-8'))
    return response

def setup_wifi_ap():
    print("Configuration de l'ESP8266...")
    send_command("AT+RST", 2) 
    send_command("AT+CWMODE=2")
    send_command('AT+CWSAP="Test","",5,0')
    send_command("AT+CIPMUX=1")  
    send_command("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80")
    print("Point d'accès configuré avec succès (sans mot de passe) !")

def handle_requests():
    print("Serveur HTTP en cours d'exécution...")
    while True:
        response = uart.read()
        if response:
            print(response.decode('utf-8'))
            if "+IPD" in response.decode('utf-8'):
                html_redirect = """HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nLocation: /captive.html\r\n\r\n"""
                send_command('AT+CIPSEND=0,' + str(len(html_redirect)))
                send_command(html_redirect) 
                send_command("AT+CIPCLOSE=0")

                time.sleep(1)

                html_page = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n
                               <html><body><h1>Bienvenue !</h1><p>Veuillez vous connecter pour accéder à Internet.</p></body></html>"""
                send_command('AT+CIPSEND=0,' + str(len(html_page))) 
                send_command(html_page)
                send_command("AT+CIPCLOSE=0")

# http://192.168.4.1
# Initialisation
setup_wifi_ap()
handle_requests()


